# How can I say from this number to this number is acceptable and otherwise unacceptable

Tags: python

How can I say from this number to this number is acceptable and otherwise unacceptable
Example
If it was from 100 to 180 it is true and if it was otherwise it is false

Comment: See the docs on conditionals : https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `if 100 <= x <= 180:`

Comment: `if x in range(100, 181)`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the context of your question is but you can use **conditional flow statements** such as `if` and `else` with **comparison operators** such as `>=` and `<=` to determine if a number is acceptable or not and run the block of code you want from there. See https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_conditions.asp for more.

```
#Conditionals
if 100 <= number <= 180: #If number is between 100 and 180
   print("Acceptable") #Run block of code you want

else: #If number is not between 100 and 180
   print("Number not accepted")
```